# how to convert bitmap to intptr in C#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

in my project I want to use EmguCV lib, but the function of EmguCV can not process the Bitmap object, so i have to convert Bitmap to some other type, Intptr is a choice but I really don't know how to code, the fellow code is abstract from my project like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(e.width, e.height,
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData data = 
    bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, e.width, e.height), 
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
int dataLength = e.width * e.height * 3;
Win32.memcpy(data.Scan0, (IntPtr)e.data, (uint)dataLength);
convertBitmapToIntptr(bmp);
```

How can I code in this function `convertBitmapToIntptr(bmp)`?

Comment: not quite sure what you are asking?

Comment: Are you looking for GetHbitmap()?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This may be an old question but if you are using EmguCV, Bitmap to IntPtr conversion can be done (as of version 2.4.2) like the following example:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("pathToBitmapFile");

Image<Bgr,byte> image = new Image<Bgr,byte>(bitmap);

IntPtr = image.Ptr;
```

See [EmguCV Documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/da3313eb-329b-a859-cd1e-4d133f0b02d4.htm)

Answer (score 0):

you want to wrap this in a class....

I've done this and called it "FastBitmap"  and you can lock it in the constructor, get the ptr, and add methods to work with the ptr